# NodeJS require module that is inside another module

Tags: node.js, module

How can I require a module that is a dependencie for another module? For example:

```
Project/foo.js
Project/nodule_modules/MyModule/node_modules/AnotherModule //dependencie of MyModule
```

How can I require "AnotherModule" from the foo.js file?

Comment: The reason for that is I don't want to duplicated modules in the final project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use in the `foo.js` module:

```
var that = require('./node_modules/MyModule/node_modules/AnotherModule');
```

See http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

Comment: var that = require('AnotherModule');

Any module in the node_modules folder gets called automatically if no prefix is passed (/, ./, ../)